# (Firebase Xcode 12 iOS 14) How can I call and set a child correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have confirmed that my Firebase project and my Xcode project are linked; I then initialized Firebase in my App.swift file as follows:

```
@main
struct TRACEApp: App {
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
      }
```

...

I then wrote the following lines in ContentView.swift to test the realtime database:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

var ref: DatabaseReference!

var writeChild: Void {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child(“user_id”).setValue(123456)
    return
}
```

However it fails on that line just before the return call, with the message "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

How can I test the realtime database such that it compiles?  I wrapped those lines in the var simply because I cannot call functions without assigning them at the top level.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue in the double quotation that you put around **user_id** which you use ( **”** ) however you should use ( **"** )

That's why it couldn't read this parameter.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the error.  I am embarrassed but relieved.

Comment: It's okay. It happened to me before that's why I figured it out. I am happy it resolved the error.